# not a statement error in if statement within switch case

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

My problem arises in the if statement - in the event that the variable "hours" is greater than 10, i wish to multiply the additional hours by 2.00 and add 9.95 to the result but i receive an error at compilation and I don't understand why. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    String choice;

    double hours;

    Scanner input = new  Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter which package you are using A, B or C? ");
    choice = input.nextLine();
    choice = choice.toUpperCase();

    System.out.print("Enter the amount of  hours used: ");
    hours = input.nextDouble();

    switch ( choice )
    {
        case "A":
            if ( hours > 10 ){
                (( hours - 10) * 2 ) + 9.95;    << ERROR: Not a statement!
                }
            else
                System.out.println("Total: $9.95");
            break;
```

For references sake this has been answered and edited to:

```
            case "A":
            if ( hours > 10 ){
                total = (( hours - 10) * 2 ) + 9.95;    // Initialised to total
                System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Total: $9.95");
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result value that generated form that line like:

```
double value = (( hours - 10) * 2 ) + 9.95;
```

Read about [valid statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) in Java

Comment: Thanks, can't beleive i didn't see that; hours - 10 must've tricked my brain into  thinking it was an assignment. Time to log off and rest my eyes.

Comment: Welcome, and don't worry its happened with all developers.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting this expression value `(( hours - 10) * 2 ) + 9.95;` to any variable.
Set the value to any variable like below :

```
double total = (( hours - 10) * 2 ) + 9.95;
```

Answer (score 1):

That line is not a Java statement, As per Oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html), statement should be a complete unit of execution

> Statements
>
> Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A
>   statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of
>   expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression
>   with a semicolon (;).
>
> - Assignment expressions
> - Any use of ++ or --
> - Method invocations
> - Object creation expressions

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your result to the hours variable like this:

```
hours = (your expression here);
```